# How to Increase the Android debugger timeout

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging, adb

I am Debugging an application but after few seconds the debugger stops and application restarts.

Any solution how can I increase the timeout.

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: no error, on break point the debugger stops and restarts the application

Comment: when the debugger is running?

Comment: Yes, when debugger is running